# MAX value from the sum of columns in Hive

Tags: hive

I'm new to Hive, and I'm stuck on a fairly simple problem. My data looks like:

```
Name---Day---Doctor Bill--- Room Bill

Rakesh  1   2500    1500

Raja    1   5000    2300

Raju    1   4500    2000

Rakesh  2   3750    2250

Rakesh  3   3550    1750

Raja    2   4500    4000

Raju    2   3450    4725
```

To find out who paid the highest of total doctor bill?

**Query:**

```
hive> insert overwrite table maxdrbill select t.name,sum(t.drbill) as totaldrbill from patient t join (select name from patient group by name order by sum(drbill) desc LIMIT 1) t1 on t.name=t1.name GROUP by t.name;
```

When I run the below query in hive I get the following error:

> FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:149 Invalid table alias or
>   column reference drbill

Comment: You've got 5 columns total, but only 4 columns of data for each row?

Answer (score 3):

**Query**

```
select name,SUM(doctorbill) as s from bills GROUP BY name ORDER BY s DESC LIMIT 1;
```

**Output**

```
Rakesh  9800
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise I believe this will be much better as the data does not need to be sorted out to get the max.

Just get the Max value after suming:
`SELECT t1.Name, MAX(TotalDrBill) FROM
(SELECT t.Name, SUM(t.drbill) as TotalDrBill FROM Patient t GROUP BY t.Name) t1`